# benefits of saving reference to built-in methods

Tags: javascript, reference

```
 ap = Array.prototype,
 aps = ap.slice,
 apsp = ap.splice,
```

I often see code like above in different frameworks. What are the benefits of this?
Why not use it directly?

Comment: Interesting side note, `$.fn === jQuery.prototype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several benefits:

1. Faster at run-time (fewer lookups to get the final result)
2. Smaller code before minification
3. Easier to reduce even more with minification
4. Less typing when coding

One should note that I think it makes the code less readable to people not already familiar with the code or its conventions because the code isn't as self documenting.  Everyone knows what `Array.prototype.splice` is but strangers don't know what `aps` is until they study the code, track down its definition and remember what it is.

---

I was asked in a comment to explain the fewer lookups issue:

For the interpreter to resolve `Array.prototype.splice`, it has to do the following:

1. Look in the local scope for the `Array` name.  It doesn't find it.
2. Look in any closures (e.g. parent scope) for the `Array` name.  It doesn't find it.
3. Look in the global scope for the `Array` name.  It finds it.
4. On the `Array` object, look for the `prototype` property.
5. On the `prototype` property, look for the `splice` property and now it finally has the function it needs.

For the interpreter to resolve `aps`, it has to do this:

1. Look in the local scope for the `aps` name.  It finds it and not it has the function it needs.

The pre-assignment to `aps` has essentially pre-done the lookups so that they are already resolved at runtime.  This removes some flexibility because if the value of the splice or prototype properties are changed, the variable `aps` won't reflect that change, but if you know they aren't supposed to change (something the run-time interpreter doesn't know), then you can take advantage of this shortcut.

Comment: how come it's fewer look-ups?? Using slice directly creates more look-ups?? How come??

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer on the fewer lookups benefit.

Comment: By closure, I just meant parent scope (levels above local for which you have access) and I realize that it can be multiple levels.  I don't see how the sequence I have is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

When used exactly as you've shown, the primary reason is to reduce the amount of typing in code that will heavily utilize the referenced method or object. Further, this can have the effect of reducing the overall size of a script. Consider:

```
Array.prototype.someFunction1 = function () { /*someFunction1 */ };
Array.prototype.someFunction2 = function () { /*someFunction2 */ };
Array.prototype.someFunction3 = function () { /*someFunction3 */ };
Array.prototype.someFunction4 = function () { /*someFunction4 */ };
```

... (284 characters) versus:

```
var ap = Array.prototype;
ap.someFunction1 = function () { /*someFunction1 */ };
ap.someFunction2 = function () { /*someFunction2 */ };
ap.someFunction3 = function () { /*someFunction3 */ };
ap.someFunction4 = function () { /*someFunction4 */ };
```

... which has 261 characters. Trivial, yes, but on a large scale this can make enough of a difference to be worthwhile in distributed code (think Google-hosted jQuery).

Sometimes, however, this is done to preserve scope through a closure:

```
  var self = this;
  this.someProperty = 5;
  var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
  myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { alert(self.someProperty); }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

One functional reason this pattern would exist would be to protect against other javascript code changing the meaning of the particular methods.  Essentially protecting from code like the following

```
Array.prototype.splice = function() {
  // This is evil
};
```

The other more likely though is the developer simply didn't want to type `Array.prototype.splice` and prefered a shorter version like `apsp`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two benefits.

- `a` is easier to minify then `Array.prototype.slice`
- `a` is a single lookup where `Array.prototype.slice` is multiple look ups

So basically they are both micro optimisations. Which are valuable in libraries because libraries care about being as efficient as possible