# Variables in javascript vs namespacing

Tags: javascript, variables, properties

What's the downside of using object properties as you would variables in Javascript? Does this not add a level of namespacing (effectively)?

```
var myProp = something;
```

vs

```
var myObj = {};

myObj.myProp = something;
```

Comment: Objects are more costly: it's one property lookup more than without. The benefits of namespaces (especially in the global scope) outweigh that by far, however.

Comment: I wouldn't consider namespacing a downside at all. Actually it's recommended in JS to avoid name clashing - see http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/ for example. Or http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: However, see [benefits of saving reference to built-in methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7488235/1048572) (and similar things)

Comment: @Bergi I know, but honestly most of the time JS chokes up because of poorly designed workflow rather than because of object property lookup. And well organized code is always a must have. Nobody will cry because of few miliseconds more to do these lookups. But a developer trying to fix something in the code jungle costs your boss a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very common to wrap code in 'modules' and use objects as a sort of namespacing. For example:

```
var fooModule = (function(){
    var private = 3;
    var privateMethod = function(){};

    var exports = {};
    exports.foo = function(){
        alert("I am public! Private is: " + private);
    }
    return exports
});
alert(private); // throws an error
fooModule.foo(); //works
```